# Upsert data.table into SQL database?

Tags: sql, r, data.table

What is the easiest way to update/insert an R `data.table` instance into an SQL database (e.g. MySQL)?  I have an instance of `data.table` with some key columns configured (via `setkey`). Now I'd like to `update` a corresponding SQL table whenever the table's primary key columns matches the table's keys (or I can map it manually) but for those rows which keys doesn't match, `insert` them.

Preferably I don't need to write the SQL for it myself. One reason is the relatively many number of data columns. Another reason is that I'd like database independence (primarily easy switching between MySQL, PostgreSQL and SQLite).

Comment: do let me know if the answer helped or not - can always add another tack or amend as required

Comment: @StephLocke [your answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29541538/199360) is about 3/4 in the "write own SQL" zone  – was looking for something similar to [dplyr](http://zevross.com/blog/2014/03/26/four-reasons-why-you-should-check-out-the-r-package-dplyr-3/) but for updates instead of queries.

Comment: I've added some info about why (AFAIK) there aren't any UPSERT functions

Comment: Incorporated Hadley's feedback about the DBI INSERT command and that a multi-stage approach could work

Answer (score 2):

Here is another solution modifying the query made by `sqlAppendTable`.

```
sql_query <- sqlAppendTable(con, "table", DT)

sql_query@.Data <- paste0(sql_query@.Data, "\n  ","ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE col1 = values(col1), col2 = values(col2)")

dbSendQuery(con, sql_query)
```

Change `col1` and `col2` for the columns that should be updated. Add others as needed. Possibly you could first determine the primary keys and make this into a generic function.

Answer (score 1):

This is tough to avoid db specific code I think due to the vagaries of different syntax across databases.

### UPSERT

The ANSI standard term is `MERGE` and (according to [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_(SQL))) the ANSI standard is supported in most of the big commercial databases. Due the relative recency of the syntax being added to the standard however, there are a lot of non-standard implementations with differing syntax across the databases that you're desiring it to be portable against.

### Database access in R

#### DBI

Much of the database I/O done by dplyr et al. is via the package [DBI](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/DBI/DBI.pdf). The DBI package has an INSERT function `dbWriteTable()` but the documentation is minimal.

#### RODBC

The [RODBC](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RODBC/RODBC.pdf) package has a `sqlUpdate()` function, however it has a number of issues:

1. Docs don't mention handling of *new* records i.e. INSERT
2. There is no granularity i.e. all values will be updated, so there would be no way to introduce partial UPSERTs
3. There can be issues with [Saves using RODBC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20215213/r-rodbc-sqlsave-crashing-disconnecting-when-too-many-columns-supplied-to-existin) that cause R session crashes.

That being said - it could work for your scenario. If it doesn't, I show below how to construct an UPSERT statement and execute it in a paramaterized fashion using RODBC. It isn't portable code, but it is dynamic, and with minimal effort you'd be able to pass columns to not be updated.

#### String construction

The default UPSERT syntax in mysql is `INSERT INTO ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ...`. This would be quite easy for you do string construction using your data.table's column names dynamically. Below is a sample function that does a parameterized UPSERT for any

```r
library(data.table)
library(RODBC)
library(RODBCext)

irisDT<- data.table(iris, key="Species")

UPSERT<-function(DT, connectionString, destTable){
 sql<- paste0("INSERT INTO ",destTable," (",paste(colnames(DT ),
                                         collapse=","),")\n",
# This bit inserts the parameterised bit i.e. where your values will go
            "VALUES (", paste(rep("?",ncol(DT )),
                              collapse=",",sep=",") ,")\n",
             "ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE \n",
# This specifies on dup. key behaviour - doesn't include key
             paste(colnames(DT )[!(colnames(DT ) %in% key(DT ))],
             "=VALUE(",
             colnames(DT )[!(colnames(DT ) %in% key(DT ))],
             ")", collapse=",\n", sep="")

              )

RODBCext::sqlExecute(channel=connectionString, 
                     query=sql, 
                     data=DT
                     )
    }

UPSERT(irisDT)
```

You may need to tweak the string construction slightly as my MySQL syntax may be off a bit.

NB Ensuring you have your key(s) set on data.table is really important here, otherwise you can't do an UPSERT, unless of course you modify the code to exclude specific columns but I was going for a dynamic solution for you.

### Multi-step process

As @hadley suggests in the comment. It is possible to do a multi-step agnostic process i.e.

1. Fetch existing values from tables
2. Identify rows that are new and INSERT them
3. Rows that are not new, send them via an update statement

This would be more verbose, and depending on the speed at which new records are inserted into your database tables could fall over where the are constraints on uniqueness and new records where inserted into the table that you would need to update instead of inserting a duplicate row.

Comment: worth to note: that is a parametrized SQL statement so it should be resistant to sql injections, definitively a way go if you allows third parties to submit any text into your data.table.

Comment: The standard for inserting data in DBI is (the confusingly named) `dbWriteTable()`. For upserts, you'd either need to construct the query yourself (as you did), or do it in three steps: perform a query to check for existing records, insert the new records, then update the existing.

Comment: @hadley ah it's sneakily hidden in `dbReadTable` documentation and of course it's DBI documentation so the description for read and write is a single line :-D Thanks for the help!

Comment: @jangorecki - UPSERT might be something to incorporate in your R for etl session content

Comment: @StephLocke not anytime soon, but leaving [dwtools](https://github.com/jangorecki/dwtools) one-liner `upsert <- function(tbl, value) value[!db(paste("SELECT DISTINCT",paste(key(value),collapse=","),tbl))][,db(.SD,tbl)]`. Can be easily translated to DBI or dplyr.

Comment: Can you file an issue on DBI to remind me to pull them apart since it's obviously confusing?